# Python find not working

Tags: python

Find in the following program does not seem to be working for '.', '!' and '?' characters. Can someone help me figure out the error.

I've tried the following things:

a. Putting a backslash in the search criteria

b. Putting two backslashes in the search criteria.

If you look at the results from Print .. you will see that find does not work correctly for sentences. Can you help me figure out what is wrong.

Thanks in advance !

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import csv

# In this exercise, we are interested in the field 'body' (which is the 5th field, 
# line[4]). The objective is to count the number of forum nodes where 'body' either 
# contains none of the three punctuation marks: period ('.'), exclamation point ('!'), 
# question mark ('?'), or else 'body' contains exactly one such punctuation mark as the 
# last character. There is no need to parse the HTML inside 'body'. Also, do not pay
# special attention to newline characters.

def mapper():
    ct = 0
    reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for line in reader:

    try:
        if line[4].strip().find('\\.') :
        writer.writerow(line)
        print ".", " found"
        ct = ct + 1
    except:
        print "Error from .", sys.exc_info()[0]

    try:
        if line[4].strip().find("!") :
        writer.writerow(line)
        print "!", " found"
        ct += 1
    except:
        print "Error from !"

    try:
        if line[4].strip().find('\\?') :
        writer.writerow(line)
        print "?", " found"
        ct += 1
    except:
        print "Error from ?"          
#            if count == 0 or count == 3 :
#                totalLines += 1
#                writer.writerow(line)



test_text = """\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"This is one sentence\"\t\"\"
\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"Also one sentence!\"\t\"\"
\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"Hey!\nTwo sentences!\"\t\"\"
\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"One. Two! Three?\"\t\"\"
\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"One Period. Two Sentences\"\t\"\"
\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"\"\t\"Three\nlines, one sentence\n\"\t\"\"
"""

# This function allows you to test the mapper with the provided test string
def main():
    import StringIO
    sys.stdin = StringIO.StringIO(test_text)
    mapper()
    sys.stdin = sys.__stdin__

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The indentation is broken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `find(...)`
>
> ```
> S.find(sub [,start [,end]]) -> int
>
> Return the lowest index in S where substring sub is found,
> such that sub is contained within S[start:end].  Optional
> arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.
>
> Return -1 on failure.
> ```

`-1` evaluates as `True`.  So if the substring is not found it will evaluate as `True`.  If the substring is found at the beginning of the string it will return `0` and evaluate as `False`.  If it is found elsewhere in the string it will return an index greater than zero and also evaluate as `True`.

Instead use `in`:

```
if '.' in line[4]:
    # ...
```

Only use `str.find` when you need to find an index.